# free domain with editing DNS records?

Tags: web-hosting

I'm looking for a free domain, I know there are some, but I want one from a place that lets me edit DNS records. See the name servers, MX Records, the technical stuff.  I know godaddy has such an interface. If my terminology is wrong then please correct me obviously.

Comment: I want a free car, free gas, and don't want to pay taxes. :p

Answer (score 1):

Here are few:

- [Co.cc](http://www.co.cc/)
- [Free-Name.org](http://free-name.org/) (trial offer based)
- [Free Domain Name](http://www.freedomainsite.com/free_domain_details.htm) (trial offer based)
- [Eu.org](http://eu.org/)

I have only tried Co.cc and Eu.org. The former one has instant registration, the latter requires admin approval (can be weeks).

Comment: FYI co.cc and eu.org only provide free subdomains. That's available in lots of places as subdomains don't need to be purchased from anywhere once you own the second-level domain (the exceptions are certain country codes, like `.co.uk`). And I would be very careful about the "free trial" offers that many spam sites have you fill out to get "free" stuff. I was foolish enough to try one of those out before and was signed up for several expensive SMS content subscription services without my consent. There's no such thing as free lunch in this world.

Comment: Free subdomain should be enough for persoanl use. More serious sites need a real domain. I'll add some words about the trial offers to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Domain registration costs money. No one is going to give domains away without some way to recoup the cost of annual registration fees. Even if they place ads on the domain, most sites aren't capable of generating ad revenue—especially not sites run by webmasters unwilling to even purchase their own domain name. After all, if you don't believe your website is worth spending $8/year on, then how serious can you be about building a quality website? (And who else would want to spend money on your site?)

If you're serious about your website, you should just fork out the cash (the cost of 3 cups of coffee a year) and buy the domain yourself. Otherwise, purchase some web hosting and get your free domain that way.